Is there a way to place an order (as admin) in name of a customer in craft commerce?
Like the title suggest. I would like to place an order in name of a customer with an admin account on the frontend. Just like in the backend you can make a manual order by first selecting a customer from a searchable dropdown.
I already made it possible to add an order with a customizable price. But I can't figure out to add a customer to that order.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Can you perhaps just use the standard Craft mechanism for impersonating that user (with the magic link)?  Or do you need the user to be an actual admin user to achieve something?

@JeremyDaalder that is indeed my last resort but it would be better if I could stay in the admin account and select the customer I'm doing the order for.

I'm not sure that is going to be possible. We were doing that prior to upgrading to Craft v4. Unfortunately it appears it was working purely by accident and it shouldn't really have been possible. Having spoken to P&T support, we've been told it will no longer work. I'll be interested to see if anyone has any other suggestions. What @JeremyDaalder has suggested seems to be the only way at the moment, unless something changes.
